# In publish raise ROSSerializationException(str(e))

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, topic, publisher, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my package that I created, there are 3 nodes currently. I also generate a custom message which is "AnchorScan".

First node does some stuff and only publishes from `/IPS` topic.
Second node subscribes to the `/IPS` topic, takes the information, do some stuff and publishes another information from `/selectedAnchors` topic.

Until now everything works fine. But;

Third node subscribes to the `/selectedAnchors` topic and does some calculations however does not publish anything from `/position` topic.

After I run this command on terminal

```
rostopic echo /position
```

I received that kind of exception.

I tried to change the queue size, rate etc. but nothing worked fine.

All raised error is here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File /home/user/my_ws/src/my_pkg/src/pkg_name/3rd_node.py", line 366, in <module>
    position_pub_sub()
  File "/home/user/my_ws/src/my_pkg/src/pkg_name/3rd_node.py", line 324, in position_pub_sub
    pub.publish(msg)     
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 886, in publish
    raise ROSSerializationException(str(e))
rospy.exceptions.ROSSerializationException: field x must be a list or tuple type
```

Thank you in advance for any help!!!

https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/1691#issue-431540502

---

Edit:

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# license removed for brevity
import rospy
from math import sqrt

from random import randint
from random import uniform
from collections import OrderedDict

from std_msgs.msg import String
from my_pkg.msg import AnchorScan    

class CalcPos2D3AIte:   

    def __init__(self, SX, SY, SZ, AX, AY, AZ, BX, BY, BZ, TZ, das, dbs):

              ## DO STUFF
              ## DO STUFF
              ## DO STUFF 

        pre_TY = (N2 -(M21*N1/M11))/(M22-(M21*M12/M11))         
            pre_TX = ((-1*M21*N1/M11) + (M21*M12/M11)*pre_TY)/(-1*M21) 

                TX = pre_TX         
                TY = pre_TY 

        self.TX_cm = int(TX*100)        
            self.TY_cm = int(TY*100)        
            self.TZ_cm = int(TZ*100)

def position_pub_sub():

    rospy.init_node('test2_positioning_node', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber('selectedAnchors', AnchorScan, callback)
    pub = rospy.Publisher('position', AnchorScan, queue_size=2)    

    rate = rospy.Rate(10)    
    
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    
     if var_control:

        msg = AnchorScan()
        tagpos = CalcPos2D3AIte(SX, SY, SZ, AX, AY, AZ, BX, BY, BZ, TZ,das, dbs)
        
         msg.x = tagpos.TX_cm
         msg.y = tagpos.TY_cm
         msg.z = tagpos.TZ_cm
                
         pub.publish(msg)     

        pub_info = "\nTX = %f \nTY = %f \nTZ = %f \n\n" % (tagpos.TX_cm,tagpos.TY_cm,tagpos.TZ_cm)
        rospy.loginfo(pub_info)

    rate.sleep()
```

Here is my AnchorScan.msg what it looks like:

```
# Timestamp
#Header header 

int32[] AnchorID 

float64[] x
float64[] y
float64[] z

float64 distance

# according to "S"
float64[] DDOA_of_anchors
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320857/in-publish-raise-rosserializationexception(str(e))/) by [elcinerdogan](https://answers.ros.org/users/36169/elcinerdogan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-04-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-11**:
The error you show is most likely caused by a mistake in the code of your "third node". Without you showing us the code, we cannot help you.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-11**:
You don't show any `import` statements. Are `N2` and friends `numpy` vectors/matrices/arrays?

---

Edit: the error message shows:

> ```
> pkg_name/3rd_node.py", line 324, in position_pub_sub
> ```

which line in the code you show is line 324? Where is `position_pub_sub`?

And: please include the definition of the `AnchorScan` message. I would also recommend to add something like `print ("type of tagpos.TX_cm: {}".format(type(tagpos.TX_cm))` right before the line where the script fails. That would let you check what the type if of `tagpos.TX_cm`.

**Comment by [elcinerdogan](https://answers.ros.org/users/36169/elcinerdogan/) on 2019-04-11**:
I added the my code snippet. There is `position_pub_sub` function here and I publish and subscribe in this function. Also line 324 indicates the;

```
 pub.publish(msg)
```

in `position_pub_sub` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok.

Your code snippet does this:

> ```
> self.TX_cm = int(TX*100)
> ```

```
[..]
msg.x = tagpos.TX_cm
```

The message definition of `AnchorScan` shows this:

> ```
> float64[] x
> ```

`x` is an array (or an unbounded list). You cannot assign a single `int` to a list.

You'll have to either use `msg.x.append(..)` or something like `msg.x = [tagpos.TX_cm]`.

Please note btw: ROS uses (derived) SI units for everything, so positions use metres. It might be good not to use centimetres for anything.

---

Edit: btw: is this a different `indoor_localization/AnchorScan` than the one documented [here](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/indoor_localization/html/msg/AnchorScan.html)? Because the one documented on the ROS wiki does not have `float64[] x`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-11**:
And some further comments: please don't use capitals in msg field names. That goes against the ROS best practices for naming things. See [wiki/Names](http://wiki.ros.org/Names).

**Comment by [elcinerdogan](https://answers.ros.org/users/36169/elcinerdogan/) on 2019-04-11**:
How could I fail to notice... I changed the type of the `tagpos.Tx_cm` from `int` into `float`. And it works. Thankss soo much.

Btw: [Here](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/indoor_localization/html/msg/AnchorScan.html) is different than my currently used msg.

**Comment by [elcinerdogan](https://answers.ros.org/users/36169/elcinerdogan/) on 2019-04-11**:
I also consider your suggestion about ROS naming. Thanks again.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-11**:\

> I changed the type of the `tagpos.Tx_cm` from `int` into `float`. And it works.

I'm not sure how that would help, seeing as `AnchorScan.x` is still a list in your message definition, and a single `float` is still not a list, but if it works for you. Ok.